# ［chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener］を使用してブラウザ上のすべての通信を取得したい

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

表題の通り，ブラウザ上のすべての通信を取得しコンソールに出力しようとしています．
以下のような拡張機能を記述し，Chromeにインストールしたのですが，適当なページにアクセスしてもコンソールには何も表示されません．

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "http://*/"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  (details) => {
    console.log(`request url is ${details}`);
  },
  {
      urls: [
          "<all_urls>"
      ]
  },
  []
);
```

コンソール画面は`chrome://extensions/`の`ビューを検証`から開いています．
[image: 開いているコンソールの場所]
コンソールにはエラーなども何も表示されていません．

Chrome拡張機能の開発は初心者なため，見ているコンソールに問題があるのか，設定に問題があるのか全く分かりません．
解決策わかる方，ご回答いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事があるようですので、Consoleではないけれどもログを採取して出力する機能は拡張機能を作らずとも元からあるのでは？ [Chrome ブラウザのデバッグログ](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=ja), [enable-loggingはChrome Enterprise専用の機能でしょうか？](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/73701667/enable-logging%E3%81%AFchrome-enterprise%E5%B0%82%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AE%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%9F?hl=ja)

Comment: @kunif  コメントありがとうございます。最終的には取得した通信を使用して何かしたいと考えています。タイトルが紛らわしかったので、修正しました。

Comment: 見つかるのが古いので通用するか不明ですが、こんな記事が参考になるかも。[chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/), [webRequest APIをざっくり理解する。(あるいはChrome拡張の作り方)](https://mzsm.me/2012/02/10/chrome17-webrequest-api/), [通信を垂れ流してなにかするChrome拡張](https://qiita.com/keiskimu/items/42e74aa46cb3c70d341f), [chrome 拡張を使って、ajax 通信の url を書き換える](https://qiita.com/osd/items/9db6c2e26ff9a45fb4d7#fnref1), [Chrome拡張機能で特定のHeaderのときだけブロックする方法](https://thr3a.hatenablog.com/entry/20181119/1542633977), [Chrome 拡張 manifest v3 で サイトブロッカーを作ってみた](https://zenn.dev/junkawa/articles/chrome-extension-mv3-siteblocker)

Comment: @kunif 
解決できました．
情報提供ありがとうございました．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決できました．

使用していた`manifest_version: 3`では`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`でURLを取得することはできないため，`manifest.json`の`manifest_version`を2に下げる必要があるようです．

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

ただし，`manifest_version: 2`が使用できるのは2023年までです．